# Regarding applying the partial derivative operation on an equality

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose that we have two multi-variable functions: $A: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ and $B: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ that are related in the following manner:
$$\nabla_x A = (\nabla_x B) \circ C, $$
where $C : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m$ is a vector-valued function, $\nabla_x$ is the partial derivative operation with respect to $x$, where convention that $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$. When I apply the partial derivative operation with respect to $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ again on this equality, I obtain, by the ordinary chain rule:
$$\nabla^2_{xx} A(x,y) = \nabla_{x} ((\nabla_x B) \circ C)(x,y) = \nabla_x C(x,y)^*\nabla_{xx}^2 B(C(x,y)).$$

Let's assume that $A$ and $B$ are both twice differentiable at $(x,y)$, to make sure that both sides are meaningful. But when I look closely, the Jacobian $\nabla_x C(x,y)^*$ is of size $(n+m) \times n$ and $\nabla_x B: \mathbb{R}^{n+m} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ so the Hessian $\nabla_{xx}^2 B(C(x,y))$ is of size $n \times (n+m)$, which effectively makes  $\nabla^2_{xx} A(x,y)$ a matrix of size $(m + n) \times (m + n)$.

Hence, $A$ and $B$ are both multi-variable functions from $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, but their partial Hessians of variables $x,x$ are of different sizes. Could you please tell me where did I go wrong with my arguments?